# Devexpress DataGridView "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference" error when I click header in Xamarin Forms App

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, datagridview, devexpress, maui

That's my datagridview and it give me error when I tap header (red rectangle).
But when I try without Tap="dataTable_Tap" this event handler. It didn't give me error.

Error :
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference'
Do you have any idea to fix this ?

```
 <dxg:DataGridView Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" x:Name="dataTable" Tap="dataTable_Tap" >
  </dxg:DataGridView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed problem.
The problem is object send datagridview with sender. Then fill DataGridGestureEventArgs with e. But e is not null but e.Item is null. This cause that expection. I change code like this below:

```
private async void dataTable_Tap(object sender, DevExpress.XamarinForms.DataGrid.DataGridGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = (DevExpress.XamarinForms.DataGrid.DataGridView)sender;
        if (menuItem != null)
        {
            var dataRow = e.Item as DataRow;

            if (dataRow != null)
            {

                //Processes
            }

        }
    }
```